# Create A CSV File Within Every Iteration Of Loop

Tags: python

I am looking to create a csv file with every iteration of a loop, but change the name of the file depending on the value of the list

```
numberOfTrainsPerHour = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 20]
```

So for example, I want the following csv files created

1.csv
2.csv
3.csv
4.csv
.....
15.csv
20.csv

Comment: What have you tried so far? what will be the content of the files?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic]. As an aside, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this will be what you expected

```
numberOfTrainsPerHour = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 20]

for i in numberOfTrainsPerHour:
    f= open(str(i)+".csv","w")
    f.close()
```

Comment: Why not use a context manager, and proper string manipulation?

Comment: @ribena1980 just want files to be created so i thought no need of it

Comment: Eh, it's probably still a good habit.

Comment: you are right but i did not do anything with the context